# LaunchDaemons file is not running?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cydia

I am creating an iPhone app that will installed by Cydia, and that app includes a LaunchDaemons plist, and a unix executable file.  The unix executable file is called from the LaunchDaemons's plist.

When I manually transfer files to an iPhone via SSH, that works fine and the plist file has `root` owner and `wheel` group, but when files are copied from Cydia installer then the unix executable file is not called from the launchDaemon's plist and the plist file has `mobile` group and `mobile` owner.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `chown` your .app files and launch daemon file BEFORE uploading to your repository.

example:

```sh
chown -R root:wheel Test.app
```

and

```sh
chown root:wheel com.foobar.Test
```

Then `dpkg -b Test` and you should get the correct ownership via Cydia.